# R CMD CHECK - Found the following (possibly) invalid DOIs

Tags: r, cran

I added a doi to my R package DESCRIPTION file and also created a citation file. R CMD CHECK passes on my own macOS computer (running R v4.2.0), and also passes on macOS Builder with no errors, warnings or notes. However, on winbuilder, I get the following note:

```
Found the following (possibly) invalid DOIs:
  DOI: 10.1111/2041-210X.13914
    From: DESCRIPTION
          inst/CITATION
    Status: Service Unavailable
    Message: 503
```

Here is where the doi appears in my DESCRIPTION file:
`Citation: Title, PO, DL Swiderski and ML Zelditch (2022) <doi:10.1111/2041-210X.13914>.`

And in my CITATION file I have the following:

```
citEntry(entry="Article",
    title = "EcoPhyloMapper: an R package for integrating geographic ranges, phylogeny, and morphology",
    author = personList(as.person("PO Title"),
        as.person("DL Swiderski"),
        as.person("ML Zelditch")),
    journal = "Methods in Ecology and Evolution",
    year = "2022",
    DOI = "10.1111/2041-210X.13914",
    textVersion = "Pascal O. Title, Donald L. Swiderski and Miriam L. Zelditch. 2022. EcoPhyloMapper: an R package for integrating geographic ranges, phylogeny, and morphology. Methods in Ecology and Evolution. https://doi.org/10.1111/2041-210X.13914")
```

After having looked at a number of other R packages as examples, I don't see what's wrong with my doi's. As only winbuilder had this note, perhaps this only pertains to R-devel, and not R-release.

Comment: Seems related to messages on the R-pkg-devel mailing list here https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2022q2/008089.html and here https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2022q2/008042.html (pulled from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/mjskay/status/1534678675551141888?s=20&t=xMmZxxQniGOlK51sP0viWw)). I think the server may block some requests. Not sure a solution has been provided yet.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, that helped clarify that there is indeed an issue. Maybe I'll try submitting to CRAN as is, add a comment, and see what happens.

Comment: That seems to be the current recommended practice. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The CRAN submission went through without any problems.